# Using Eclipse Vorto to describe "PDDL-like" actions

Tags: eclipse-vorto

I started using Eclipse Vorto for my project and, as part of my device description, I would like to include operations with  preconditions and effects, as in the case of PDDL (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_Domain_Definition_Language).
For example, I would like to include the following action (using the PDDL formalism):

```
   (:action move
    :parameters (?from ?to)
    :precondition (and (at ?from))
    :effect (and (at ?to)
                (not (at ?from))))
```

I read the vortolang documentation (https://github.com/eclipse/vorto/blob/master/docs/vortolang-1.0.md) and the only class that partially fits the purpose is the `Operation` class. The previous PDDL action would be mapped to the following:

```
move(from as string, to as string)
```

Of course, in this way preconditions and effects would be lost. Is there a "vorto-like" way to express this kind of PDDL actions?

Comment: I am entirely clueless with regards to PDDL, so this comment might be garbage, but... could you not implement your operation with nested datatypes? So instead of `move(from as string, to as string)`, you would have something like `move(movement as PDDLMove)`. Then the latter would contain mandatory `from` and `to`, and (optional?) `precondition as PDDLPrecondition` and `effect as PDDLEffect` - obviously the grammar itself would not enforce any validation of `?from` and `?to` across params, precondition and effect...